# What does "eis" mean in "and for[eis] whom we exist" in 1 Corinthians 8:6?

Tags: 1-corinthians

**1 Corinthians 8:6** ESV

> "yet for us there is one God, the Father, from whom are all things and **for** whom we exist, and one Lord, Jesus Christ, through whom are all things and through whom we exist." My emphasis. [for/*eis*]

Does *eis*, here translated as "for", suggest purpose. ie: that we exist for God's purposes?

**Romans 11:36** ESV

> "For from him and through him and **to**  him are all things. To him be glory forever. Amen." [to/*eis*].

In Ro 11:36 "*eis*" is translated "to". Perhaps suggesting  movement "towards/to", or further going "into" the mystery of God.

Answer (score 1):

**1 Corinthians 8:6**

[image]

**Romans 11:36**

[image]

The definition given by the [Strong's](https://biblehub.com/greek/1519.htm) is:

- **eis:** to or into (indicating the point reached or entered, of place, time, fig. purpose, result)
- **Original Word:** εἰς
- **Part of Speech:** Preposition
- **Transliteration:** eis
- **Phonetic Spelling:** (ice)
- **Definition:** to or into (indicating the point reached or entered, of place, time, purpose, result)
- **Usage:** into, in, unto, to, upon, towards, for, among.

**In 1 Corinthians 8:6, the Greek word "eis" carries the sense of purpose or direction, indicating the intended goal or end result.** So, when it says "for whom we exist," it implies that our existence is directed towards God's purposes or for His glory.

The word "eis" is rather versatile and can convey various nuances depending on the context. In this verses' context, it signifies the purpose or end goal of our existence, that we exist for God's purposes or to fulfill His will.

So the meaning of "eis" in 1 Corinthians 8:6:

- Purpose or direction | "for whom we exist"
- Goal or intended end | Our existence is directed towards fulfilling
  God's purposes or for His glory.

[Thayer's Greek Lexicon](https://biblehub.com/greek/1519.htm) notes:

- answering to his purposes (the final cause), Romans 11:36; ἐξ οὗ τά
  πάντα καί ἡμεῖς εἰς αὐτόν, 1 Corinthians 8:6